# Build Issues in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

The following errors occurs in Jenkins on running a job.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS<br>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
[INFO] Total time: 5.785s<br>
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 24 16:40:15 IST 2013<br>
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/42M<br>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data<br>
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Selenium Code\workspace\pom.xml to org.corp.selenium.framework/Selenium_Code/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Selenium_Code-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom<br>
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Selenium Code\workspace\target\Selenium_Code-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to org.corp.selenium.framework/Selenium_Code/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Selenium_Code-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar<br>
FATAL: hudson.maven.MavenBuild.isInProgress()Z<br>
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.maven.MavenBuild.isInProgress()Z<br>
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild.access$700(MavenBuild.java:94)<br>
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl2.close(MavenBuild.java:621)<br>
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuilder.end(AbstractMavenBuilder.java:106)<br>
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun<br>(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:839)<br>
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:562)<br>
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)<br>
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)<br>
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)<br>
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)<br>
```

As you can see from the above console output from jenkins, the below listed changes happen:

1. Build is successful
2. The Jar files gets created and succesfully installed into maven repository
3. Still the job fails with the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`
   exception.

Please let me know, how to fix this exception?

Comment: looks like some incompatible versions of Jenkins / maven.

Comment: Jenkins ver. 1.536, Maven 3.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue here and  downgrade of Maven Project Plugin to version 2.0-beta-1 solved it.
I hope it helps

Best Regards

Comment: It was a version problem. I upgraded the Jenkins to the latest version and the issue got fixed automatically.